# Generating json to parse error

Tags: json, perl

I am generating a Json string, which isn't generating good Json. To me it looks 
good, but I have a mistake somwhere. I can't find where it is and how to remove it.
Here is the entire source (since it is very short).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( decode_json );

sub getJsonStr{
    print "Enter the name of the person: ";
    my $name = <>;
    print "Enter the age of the person: ";
    my $age = <>;
    my $json = '{
            "name" :"'.$name.'",
            "age"  :"'.$age.'"
           }';
}

my $jsonStr = getJsonStr();

print $jsonStr;

my $jobj = decode_json($jsonStr);
```

Comment: `'{"name" :"'.$name.'" ...'` better written as `q({"name" :"$name" ...)`

Comment: @TLP … `qq({"name": "$name", ...})` in order for `$name` to interpolate (not just `q(…)`).

Comment: @amon Of course, I brainfarted there. Although I would say now to use Quentin's solution instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input in order to remove all trailing newlines from the `$name` and `$age` variables, before using them into your JSON. And by that I mean:

```
my $name = <>;
chomp $name;

my $age = <>;
chomp $age;
```

These newlines was the reason of your error.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is caused by not escaping inputted characters which have special meaning or which are not allowed in JSON strings.

The method you are using to input the data is guaranteed to have a new line character at the end of it. Presumably you don't want that, so you should remove it (with `chomp`) rather than escaping.

That doesn't stop the user entering other characters with special meaning though. If you want to generate JSON, then use a JSON library, don't just mash strings together. You're already using JSON.pm, so get the encoder from that as well as the decoder.

```
sub getJsonStr {
    print "Enter the name of the person: ";
    my $name = <>;
    chomp $name;
    print "Enter the age of the person: ";
    my $age = <>;
    chomp $age;
    my $json = encode_json({ name => $name, age => $age });
}
```